# Oracle 11g XE - Giving granting privileges to a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I need to use a stored procedure to give certain privilges over a view to users.

However I don't know how to give the procedure the necessary privileges to grant users privileges.

Comment: Assuming you are creating a definer's rights stored procedure, it will run with the privileges that are assigned directly (not via a role) to the user that owns the procedure.  So the owner of the procedure would need to have permission to give another user access to the view granted directly.  Beyond that, it's hard to be very specific without seeing an example of what you're struggling with.  I'm not sure what you're trying, what error(s) you're getting, or what your views look like so it's hard to guess what problems you might be having.

Comment: I've created and run the procedure with a user that has granting priveleges.

Comment: The error I'm getting is 'not enough privileges'

Comment: We'd need to see a reproducible test case.  For example, the `CREATE VIEW`, the `GRANT` statement(s) on the view, the stored procedure you're using, etc.  Not knowing who owns the view, what table(s) the view references, what other object(s) the view references, what the stored procedure is doing, who owns the stored procedure, etc. it's hard to guess what privilege you're missing.